# Plugin for CKEditor split to multiple js files

Tags: ckeditor

I am creating a new CK Editor plugin, and want to split the javascript code to more than one .js file
Currently I do not see a way to load my second .js file.

My structure:

- plugin.js --> this is the main file containing the plugin structure/code
- manip.js --> contains text manipulation functions, that are called by the plugin (800+ lines)

Is this possible? What is your recommendation - put all code into plugin.js or would you also split code to two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting your code makes sense only if it isn't required from the very beginning. E.g. CKEditor loads dialogs' code on demand and the same happens with paste from word filter. These files very often are big (>1k LOC) and it's not critical to load them at the beginning.

If you want to load your file on demand check this part of pastefromword plugin: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/pastefromword/plugin.js#L95-L108

Here's the documentation: [CKEDITOR.scriptLoader](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.scriptLoader), [CKEDITOR.getUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-getUrl).